# How to upload Processing sketches to the web

Tags: java, html, processing, processing.js

I have Processing, version 3.0, and I am interested to export any sketch to HTML but I have no clue of how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/).

You should be able to use this from the Processing editor by going to the "modes" dropdown (it says "Java" by default), selecting "Add Mode...", then finding "JavaScript Mode" and installing it.

Once it's installed, you can use JavaScript mode to write Processing code and deploy it as HTML and JavaScript. Note that you won't be able to use any Java libraries like minim though.

Comment: Hi, well... it says "0.3.3 not compatible" and I can't install it.

Comment: @sfdsdffdgfdzg Processing.js is still catching up to the latest version of Processing. If you want to deploy as JavaScript, you might have to go back to an older version of Processing for now. Stay tuned to the Processing.js website for updates.

Comment: processing.js is abandoned. [P5.js replaces and supersedes it](https://github.com/processing/p5.js).